# json formatting in python

Tags: python, json

records variable contains following data

> [(38177492.733055562, 38177482.886388876), (39370533.190833323,
>   40563588.018611118), (34598340.198888883,
>   33405299.966944441), (40563586.926666655,
>   35791393.990277782), (35791394.635833345,
>   36984434.221388899), (33405296.804722216,
>   38177491.020277783), (38177487.716111109,
>   34598350.781944439), (39370531.633888908,
>   36984439.543333329), (38177489.396111116,
>   38177487.920833334), (39370529.841666684,
>   33405297.846666656), (33405301.882777769,
>   33405297.091944445), (39370533.917222217,
>   35791396.884444445), (36984443.128055543,
>   38177492.467500001), (34598343.099166669,
>   35791389.096111104), (32212259.345555563,
>   35791393.736388884), (34598345.439444438,
>   31019213.084444441), (39370531.074722223,
>   38177482.122222222), (35791401.003333338,
>   34598351.12555556), (34598344.94194445,
>   38177486.527500004), (36984439.948888898,
>   35791396.906944446), (38177487.922499999,
>   36984440.749722227), (40563581.584166668,
>   42949669.236111119), (36984437.315277785,
>   35791396.236388907), (32212259.083611108,
>   41756619.713333331), (38177489.083888903,
>   38177494.218888886)]

```
datalist= defaultdict( list )
datalist['startdate'].append()
datalist['enddate'].append(startDate)
datalist['minute'].append(info[0][2]/60)
datalist['data'].append(records) # look the data part in json
data = simplejson.dumps(datalist, indent=4)
```

if i print data variable's content then its converting data into

```
{
    "startdate": [
        "21-02-2011 00:00:00"
    ],
    "enddate": [
        "21-02-2011 00:00:00"
    ],
    "minute": [
        60
    ],
    "data": [
        [                  // i want to remove this brack and its matching closing bracket 
                           // but as records is a list so simplejson is converting it into
                           // sub array in json.
            [
                38177492.733055562,
                38177482.886388876
            ],
            [
                39370533.190833323,
                40563588.018611118
            ],
            [
                34598340.198888883,
                33405299.966944441
            ],
            [
                40563586.926666655,
                35791393.990277782
            ],
            [
                35791394.635833345,
                36984434.221388899
            ],
            [
                33405296.804722216,
                38177491.020277783
            ],
            [
                38177487.716111109,
                34598350.781944439
            ],
            [
                39370531.633888908,
                36984439.543333329
            ],
            [
                38177489.396111116,
                38177487.920833334
            ],
            [
                39370529.841666684,
                33405297.846666656
            ],
            [
                33405301.882777769,
                33405297.091944445
            ],
            [
                39370533.917222217,
                35791396.884444445
            ],
            [
                36984443.128055543,
                38177492.467500001
            ],
            [
                34598343.099166669,
                35791389.096111104
            ],
            [
                32212259.345555563,
                35791393.736388884
            ],
            [
                34598345.439444438,
                31019213.084444441
            ],
            [
                39370531.074722223,
                38177482.122222222
            ],
            [
                35791401.003333338,
                34598351.12555556
            ],
            [
                34598344.94194445,
                38177486.527500004
            ],
            [
                36984439.948888898,
                35791396.906944446
            ],
            [
                38177487.922499999,
                36984440.749722227
            ],
            [
                40563581.584166668,
                42949669.236111119
            ],
            [
                36984437.315277785,
                35791396.236388907
            ],
            [
                32212259.083611108,
                41756619.713333331
            ],
            [
                38177489.083888903,
                38177494.218888886
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `defaultdict(list)` in the first place, and storing everything as lists?

Comment: Well i am new to python and i really don't have enough idea sorry so it would be really nice that you point out things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you really don't need a defaultdict here, a normal dict will do just fine.

```
datalist = {}
datalist['startdate'] = startDate
datalist['enddate'] = endDate
```

Answer (score 2):

`datalist['data'] = record`    works ?